# Reading data from kafka topic via golden gate

Tags: apache-kafka, oracle-golden-gate

I have a Spring Boot code which reads data from Kafka topic. The code works as expected when data is feed to the topic via Kafka Producer Console. When I try to push data into the kafka topic via Golden Gate, the code doesn't reads the data from the topic, although I can see the golden gate is able to write the data into the kafka topic. Can anyone suggest why this change in  behavior?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.bson.Document;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

import kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator;
import kafka.consumer.KafkaStream;

public class VideoConsumer implements Runnable {
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> kafkaStream;
    private int threadNumber;

    public VideoConsumer(KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> kafkaStream, int threadNumber) {
        this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
        this.kafkaStream = kafkaStream;
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = kafkaStream.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            byte[] messageData = it.next().message();
            try {
                //String videoFromMessage = objectMapper.readValue(messageData, String.class);
                //byte[] videoFromMessage = it.next().message();
                //System.out.print("got message");

                String streamData = new String(messageData);
                System.out.print("Thread:" + threadNumber + ".Consuming video: " + streamData + "\n");
                String changed=streamData.toString();
                int pos=changed.lastIndexOf("}}");
                String change=changed.substring(0,pos );
                change=change.replace("}}", "}},");
                String res=change.concat("}}"); 

                String result="[" +res+ "]";
                System.out.println(result);
                JSONArray json;

                    json = new JSONArray(result);
                    Map<String, List<JSONObject>> orderMongo = new HashMap<>();
                    Map<String, List<JSONObject>> orderItemMongo = new HashMap<>();
                    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
                    MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("Mongotest");  
                    MongoCollection<Document> table = db.getCollection("test1");
                    Document doc1=new Document();
                    //Gson gson=new Gson();
                    BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();

                    for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject(i);
                       if(obj.getString("table").equals("TEST.S_ORDER_MONGO1")){
                        List<JSONObject> list = orderMongo.getOrDefault(obj.getString("table").equals("TEST.S_ORDER_MONGO1"),new ArrayList<>());
                        list.add(obj);
                        orderMongo.put(obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("ROW_ID"),list);
                       }
                       else if(obj.getString("table").equals("TEST.S_ORDER_ITEM_MONGO1")){
                           List<JSONObject> nextlist = orderItemMongo.getOrDefault(obj.getString("table").equals("TEST.S_ORDER_ITEM_MONGO1"),new ArrayList<>());
                        nextlist.add(obj);
                     orderItemMongo.put(obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("ORDER_ID"),nextlist);

                       }
                    }
                    System.out.println(orderMongo);
                    System.out.println(orderItemMongo);
                   // System.out.println(orderItemMongo);
                    for (Entry<String, List<JSONObject>> entry : orderMongo.entrySet()) {
                        for(Entry<String, List<JSONObject>> entry1 : orderItemMongo.entrySet()){
                            if(entry.getKey().equals(entry1.getKey())){
                            //String gsonString=gson.toJson(entry.getValue());  
                            //System.out.println(gsonString);
                                List<JSONObject> listnext = entry.getValue();
                                List <JSONObject> orderlineList=entry1.getValue();
                                for(JSONObject obj:listnext){
                            Document doc = new Document("STATUS_CD", obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("STATUS_CD"));
                                if(obj.getJSONObject("after").isNull("INTEGRATION_ID")==true){
                            doc.append("INTEGRATION_ID", null);}

                            doc.append("X_CUST_REF", obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("X_CUST_REF"));
                            doc.append("REQ_SHIP_DT",obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("REQ_SHIP_DT"));

                            if(obj.getJSONObject("after").isNull("QUOTE_ID")==true){
                            doc.append("QUOTE_ID",null);}

                            doc.append("ACCNT_ID",obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("ACCNT_ID"));
                            doc.append("ACTIVE_FLG",obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("ACTIVE_FLG"));
                            doc.append("PROCESS_TIMESTAMP",obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("PROCESS_TIMESTAMP"));
                            doc.append("CONTACT_ID",obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("CONTACT_ID"));
                            doc.append("BU_ID", obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("BU_ID"));
                            doc.append("SHIP_CON_ID",obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("SHIP_CON_ID"));
                            doc.append("LAST_UPD", obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("LAST_UPD"));

                            if(obj.getJSONObject("after").isNull("X_CLOSE_DT")==true){
                            doc.append("X_CLOSE_DT", null);}

                            doc.append("X_SUB_STAT", obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("X_SUB_STAT"));
                            doc.append("ORDER_NUM", obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("ORDER_NUM"));
                            doc.append("SOFT_DELETE", obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("SOFT_DELETE"));
                            doc.append("ROW_ID", obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("ROW_ID"));
                            doc.append("LAST_UPD_BY",obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("LAST_UPD_BY"));
                            doc.append("REV_NUM",obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("REV_NUM"));
                            doc.append("ORDER_DT", obj.getJSONObject("after").getString("ORDER_DT"));
                            for(JSONObject object:orderlineList){
                                if(object.getJSONObject("after").isNull("ASSET_ID")==true){

                                    doc1.append("ASSET_ID", null);}

                                if(object.getJSONObject("after").isNull("SERV_ACCNT_ID")==true){
                                doc1.append("SERV_ACCNT_ID", null);}
                                doc1.append("REQ_SHIP_DT",object.getJSONObject("after").getString("REQ_SHIP_DT"));

                                if(object.getJSONObject("after").isNull("X_PROD_DESC")==true){
                                doc1.append("X_PROD_DESC",null);}

                                if(object.getJSONObject("after").isNull("SHIP_CON_ID")==true){
                                doc1.append("SHIP_CON_ID",null);}

                                doc1.append("X_BES_STATUS",object.getJSONObject("after").getString("X_BES_STATUS"));
                                doc1.append("ROW_ID",object.getJSONObject("after").getString("ROW_ID"));
                                doc1.append("STATUS_CD",object.getJSONObject("after").getString("STATUS_CD"));
                                doc1.append("ORDER_ID",object.getJSONObject("after").getString("ORDER_ID"));
                                if(object.getJSONObject("after").isNull("COMPLETED_DT")==true){
                                doc1.append("COMPLETED_DT",null);}

                                doc1.append("LAST_UPD",object.getJSONObject("after").getString("LAST_UPD"));
                                doc1.append("SOFT_DELETE",object.getJSONObject("after").getString("SOFT_DELETE"));
                                doc1.append("INTEGRATION_ID",object.getJSONObject("after").getString("INTEGRATION_ID"));
                                doc1.append("X_CDD",object.getJSONObject("after").getString("X_CDD"));
                                doc1.append("ACTION_CD",object.getJSONObject("after").getString("ACTION_CD"));
                                doc1.append("X_ORDER_ITEM_SUBSTATUS",object.getJSONObject("after").getString("X_ORDER_ITEM_SUBSTATUS"));
                                if(object.getJSONObject("after").isNull("X_APPT_REF")==true){

                                doc1.append("X_APPT_REF",null);}

                                if(object.getJSONObject("after").isNull("X_CANCELLED_DT")==true){
                                doc1.append("X_CANCELLED_DT",null);}

                                doc1.append("PROD_ID",object.getJSONObject("after").getString("PROD_ID"));

                                if(object.getJSONObject("after").isNull("SERVICE_NUM")==true){

                                doc1.append("SERVICE_NUM",null);}

                                if(object.getJSONObject("after").isNull("MUST_DLVR_BY_DT")==true){


                                doc1.append("MUST_DLVR_BY_DT",null);}

                                doc1.append("ROLLUP_FLG",object.getJSONObject("after").getString("ROLLUP_FLG"));
                                doc1.append("ROOT_ORDER_ITEM_ID",object.getJSONObject("after").getString("ROOT_ORDER_ITEM_ID"));
                                doc1.append("BILL_ACCNT_ID",object.getJSONObject("after").getString("BILL_ACCNT_ID"));
                                doc1.append("PROCESS_TIMESTAMP",object.getJSONObject("after").getString("PROCESS_TIMESTAMP"));
                                doc1.append("QTY_REQ",object.getJSONObject("after").getString("QTY_REQ"));

                            }
                            doc.append("ORDERLINE", doc1);
                            table.insertOne(doc);
                                }
                            }
                    }
            }
       }        


            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Shutting down Thread: " + kafkaStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very general question. It does not work. Provide the script that is not working.

Comment: Hi @AdamLeszczyński , I have provided the code. This class has the run() method which is evoked from SpringApplication.run. Can you suggest why the code doesn't read from the topic. There is another class having the config details.